# Is the product of (modified) adjacency matrices of two matchings necessarily symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Consider $n$ vertices, and two (not necessarily perfect) matchings $M_1$ and $M_2$. With the following definition of a (modified) adjacency matrix of a matching, can we claim that $A(M_1)\cdot A(M_2)$ is always symmetric?

**Definition**: A (modified) adjacency matrix $A(M)$ of a matching $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix defined as follows: if $M$ matches a node $i$ with a node $j$, then $A(M)_{i,j} = A(M)_{j,i} = 1/2$. If $i$ is not matched with any node, then $A(M)_{i,i}=1$. All other entries are zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $A(M_1)A(M_2)$ need not be symmetric. Here is a counter example.

 Consider the graph $K_4$ on the vertex set $[4]$.

 Let $M_1=\big \{ \{1,3 \} \big \}$ and $M_2=\big \{ \{1,2 \}, \{3,4 \} \big \}$. Then
$$
A(M_1)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
,
A(M_2)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A(M_1)A(M_2)= \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Observe that $A(M_1)A(M_2)$ is not symmetric.

---

Product of two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ is symmetric if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute. That is, $(AB)^T=AB$ iff $AB=BA$.

Comment: +1 Pretty much the same answer I came up with after realizing my error, and you beat me to it.  I left mine up to include the combinatorial interpretation of the product of matrices.

Comment: Was this question already answered?

Comment: No, yours was posted first.  I posted an incorrect answer, deleted and edited once I realized the mistake.  Once I submitted the corrections, saw your counterexample, which is basically the same as mine.  Your correct answer was posted first.

Answer (score 2):

False.  Take the matching $M_1$ on four vertices that only matches $v_1$ to $v_2$, and let $M_2$ match $v_1$ to $v_3$ and $v_2$ to $v_4$.  Then the matrices are 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

whose product is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.25 \\
0 & 0 & 0.25 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I thought about these matrices as $\frac{1}{2}$ the adjacency matrix of your matching with two loops at isolated vertices.  Then the product of matrices is $\frac{1}{4}$ times the matrix whose entries are paths from $i$ to $j$ of length $2$ going first along an edge in the first graph then along an edge in the second graph.  After first thinking that this was obviously symmetric, drawing out an example ( this one ) I saw it was not.